# How can I get a JSONOBject of a Web Service?

Tags: android, json, web-services, androidhttpclient

I'm trying get a JSONObject of a Web Service. To do this I'm using HttpClient with HttpResponse. When web service does return JSON I change return to a string and try create a JSONObject but still doesn´t work and return null.

How can I do this ?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public static JSONObject get(String url){       
        JSONObject jsonObj = null;

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if(entity != null){
                String s = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(s);                
            }           
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return jsonObj; 
    }
```

Comment: First of all you have Log for status of `response` if it is `OK` then you can do like `entity = response.getEntity();` and `is = entity.getContent();`

Comment: yep, if I return a String does print in Log.i my JSON, but I want return a JSONObject.

Comment: with the current libs... where GSON, Volley, etc are available, there are still people using this... oh well... some are still masochists.

Comment: @cesztoszule but GSON is deprecated no ? look at here: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list?can=1